# Where does a comma go before a song title?

Tags: punctuation, commas, quotations

Would it be: She sang the song "The Yellow Submarine nicely."
or would it be: She sang the song, "The Yellow Submarine nicely."

Comment: There's no reason to use a comma in that sentence. The quotation marks set off the song title from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: What prompted you to place the word {nicely} within the quotes for the title of the song?

Comment: @BlessedGeek maybe the song isn't from the Beatles ;)

Comment: Then the subsequent question that should prevail would be - why is the title of the song {The Yellow Submarine nicely} rather than {The Yellow Submarine Nicely} ? Shouldn't every non-preposition word of the title be camelcased?

Comment: Then my further subsequent compulsion is to ask - since it's a title of a song and not a quotation of a conversation or writing, why does the phrasing of the question have the period/full-stop within the quotes for the title? Shouldn't it be phrased {*She sang the song "The Yellow Submarine Nicely".*} ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the Beatles song, then:

If the song must be identified:

> She sang the song "Yellow Submarine" nicely.

If the song is already obvious, then:

> She sang the song, "Yellow Submarine," nicely.

Similarly,

> I saw the movie “Star Wars” yesterday. [telling the listener which movie; restrictive appositive]
>
> I saw the movie, “Star Wars,” yesterday. [already known which movie; non-restrictive appositive]

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using the same rules as you would when giving a direct quote usually works best. Because, in actuality, these ARE quotes; quotes of the songwriter. I love the song, "Happy Together" by The Turtles.
 But, when not using it that way; for example, when comparing two or more, then you are not quoting the writer, you are just referring to them. E.g.: "Bohemian Rhapsody" is so music better than "Shake It Off".
Hope this helps!